# javascript hash function for url's - url matching for adserver targeting

Tags: javascript, regex, json, hash

I'm looking for a js hash function/script for url hashing and searching on the client.

I'd like to use it to tag my pages for a adserver. The idea is to include a list of url hashes in the script. If there is the exact match in the hash table I send the keywords assigned to the hash to the adserver. If there isn't an exact match i'd like to get the closest url, so it falls back to lets say parent folder or domain.

E.g fallback by matching upper folder:

- hash of domain.com/categorie1/subcategorie1/page1/ (no match)
- check hash domain.com/categorie1/subcategorie1/ (no match)
- chech hash domain.com/categorie1/ match --> keyword 1 assigned to ad request

E.g. finding closest by hashcode distance

- hash of domain.com/categorie1/subcategorie1/page1/ abc
- abc is not in hashtable (no match)
- cba-abc distance = 50
- bbc-abc distance = 25
- aba-abc distance = 3 (this is the closest match, take the keywords from this url)

stupid idee! not sure though, if it is possible at all? what you think? know any js doing this?

Thx, i really appreciate your help and thoughts!

Comment: I don't understand your example.

Comment: it first looks for the same url, than it shortens the url folder by folder and looks for a match. (matching approach) I heard that hash codes for geo locations exist which allow to calculate an approximate distance and find the closest two points. Such algorithmes are used e.g. in mysql and mongo to find to close points or do geographic search. I thought it may be possible to do something similar with urls? clearer now?

Comment: Why would you need to? URLs have a maximum length, and you could just iterate up the folder path until you find a match.

Comment: I'm also thinking of building a json tree. Just considering alternative. having 500 urls an advantage may be a lower storage footprint?